# display tty1 on one monitor and display tty2 on second monitor (usb terminal)

Tags: debian, graphics, multi-monitor

I have Debian 7 in console only mode; is there a way I can display different programs on 2 monitors?

example:

Screen one is the primary screen and this is to display my PoS application
Screen two is the one that is facing the customer so I would like this one to display the "Customer graphical" program (basically it lists all items that have been brought so far plus a running total and item count)

Can this be done or have I managed to find something that is easier on Windows then Linux? (It is impossible on DOS as it only can handle one screen)

Comment: I think you're confusing concepts.  TTYs don't apply to the graphical environment but to command line sessions.